# Can't pull flexbox container to footer after page resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After resizing of page nested content-box get down thru main div and break it.

It's look like so:
[image]

Here is live [example](http://shm.code123.org/) (Content loading work on Chrome only). Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5pjs37v/)

The css code that response for displaying problem (as I think) part:

```
.Central {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-grow: 1;
      height: auto;
    }
    .LeftSide {
      background-color: #ddd0d1;
      flex-grow: 8;

    }
    .RightSide{
      background-color: #965254;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `height: 100vh`, use `min-height: 100vh`.

```
.MainContainer {
    background-color: #fee9ea;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    /* height: 100vh; <-- remove fixed height */
    min-height: 100vh; /* new */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

That will release your main container to expand with the content.

If you prefer the fixed height, then keep the `height: 100vh` and add vertical scroll:

```
.LeftSide {
    background-color: #ddd0d1;
    flex-grow: 8;
    overflow: auto; /* new */
}
```